# The origins of xbow

Tags: slang, etymology

"xbow", sometimes spelled "x-bow", "XBow" or even "x bow", is a common contraction in the gaming environment which means "crossbow". Having started gaming as a child, I've never paid too much attention to it, largely because my English was a lot worse than now.

Approaching the barrier between B2 and C1, however, I started to wonder about the etymology of many things I am used to. I tried to use Google, but it has either pointed me at some gaming-related websites or at pages explaining the general meaning of the word "crossbow", which I don't need.

Comment: Gaming communities often come up with terms or abbreviations that stick but which have little relevance elsewhere. Some may be game specific or specific to a genre. For example "exp" or "XP" is experience or experience points. But I doubt you will find those terms used anywhere other than role playing games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, writing a question at StackExchange actually is magical. I tried it again with a slightly different spelling of the contraction right before actually posting the question, and have [found out that "X" is used as an abbreviation for "cross"](http://www.yourdictionary.com/xbow), as the letter is basically a cross.

Wow! Learning new stuff is fun.

Comment: Or "Christ" as in **Xmas**.  In addition, it commonly refers to something extraordinary and/or enigmatic (like the **X-Men**), and is also where pirates bury their treasure (**X marks the spot**).  Oh, and it can also be a symbol for kisses **XXXX**.

Comment: Does the "X for Christ" have something to do with the way he died?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy X in Xmas comes from the greek letter Chi. See [Xmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmas).

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy  I'm sure part of the historical appeal of this abbreviation is that the X-shape is like a leaning cross, but as Brandin says, it's likely from the Greek Χριστός  (Christos).